# Is it possible to get the original parameter name using nameof() in a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, c#-6.0, nameof

I need to create a CSV style string of parameters mapped to their values.
For example:

```
static void MyMethod(int i, string str, object obj, bool flag)
{
    string example = "i=123,str=Hello,obj=1.0,flag=false";
}
```

Called like:

```
MyMethod(123, "Hello", 1.0, false);
```

I would want an output like the string `example`.

I need to do this for a large number of methods which have many different signatures and may not use all parameters in each method with no discernible pattern - so I have tried to create a method to automate the process somewhat.

I have attempted to solve this using a delegate and nameof:

```
delegate string GetParametersDelegate(params object[] parameters);

static GetParametersDelegate GetParametersFunc = (parameters) =>
{
    return string.Join(",", parameters
        .Select(parameter => nameof(parameter) + "=" + parameter));
};
```

Called like:

```
static void MyMethod(int i, string str, object obj, bool flag)
{
    string notTheResultIWant = GetParameters(i, str, obj, flag);
    // notTheResultIWant = "parameter=123,parameter=Hello,parameter=1.0,parameter=false"
}
```

I have found this results in the name of the variable in the lambda being used instead of the original parameter name - so every value is incorrectly mapped to `parameter` from the lambda.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible to achieve? Or is there another way I can approach this problem?

Comment: How about creating a class with all these parameters and passing it instead. That way you can "capture" the parameter names in the constructor and reuse them everywhere else.

Comment: I've just clarified in the question, but there are many different method signatures - I can see what you're suggesting and it's quite interesting actually, I'm going to have a look at it. My only concern is the exponential growth of this class!

Comment: Does this question help you at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489799/how-to-write-a-custom-poco-serializer-deserializer

Comment: It does - it is another possible way for me to approach this. If possible however I would like to avoid reflection as this code should be performant.

Comment: If you want to be efficient at run time, you'd be better served by a Roslyn analyzer/fix that validates and extracts that info from the method signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution I came up with is getting ParameterInfo[] of called method via its MethodInfo:

```
delegate string GetParametersDelegate(Delegate method, params object[] parameters);

static GetParametersDelegate GetParametersFunc = (method, parameters) =>
{
    var paramNames = method.Method.GetParameters().Select(pInfo => pInfo.Name);
    return
        paramNames.Select((name, index) => $"{name}={parameters[index]?.ToString() ?? "null"}")
            .Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a},{b}");
};
```

You can call:

```
static void MyMethod(int i, string str, object obj, bool flag)
{
    var method = (Action<int, string, object, bool>)MyMethod;
    var notTheResultIWant = GetParametersFunc(method, i, str, obj, flag);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `_` as a parameter name if you're actually going to use the parameter.

Comment: thx. Meaningless name should be avoided in answer. Edited my answer.